# Issues with print Prusa i3 infill breaking and causing clogs

Tags: print-quality, prusa-i3, troubleshooting, infill

I'm having some issues with my Prusa i3 prints. I'm trying to print the default beer opener print that came with the Prusa's memory card but the infill will break causing clogging and now allowing the print to finish. I've attached a picture of one of the failed prints.

[image]

I've checked Prusa's website and tried tightening the extruder gears and made sure the gears are clean. I'm using the PLA sent with the printer (1.75 mm) and with a default G-code file so I'm fairly sure it is a hardware issue, but I'm not sure what the issue could be.

[Here is the link](https://blog.prusaprinters.org/7-problems-affecting-quality-of-3d-prints/) that I've used to help me troubleshoot.

Comment: Hi welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! I doubt whether the infill breaking up causes a clog, I would rather say it is the other way around. As this is a pre-sliced model, a similar question "[Infill is rough - how to enhance?](/q/8229)" might not be applicable, nor can you do anything about the print file. This rests whether you have the correct material loaded (temperature wise) and a good first layer. Please add by [edit] what material you use and what the print requires and post an image of the bottom of the print.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was the filament sent with the printer was PETG and not PLA like this gcode file called for.

Comment: Thanks for posting your own solution, please accept this after 48 hours!

Comment: this means the temperature is off by some 30°C.

Answer (score 2):

Try calibrating your Z again. It is hard to tell based on the picture, but it could be too close to the build plate, and thus is dragging while crossing the infill section, or it could be too far away and thus is not getting good layer adhesion.